# Изменить соотношение элементов в окне PyQt при масштабировании и изменить действие по нажатию кнопки

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt, qt-designer, qlayout

У меня есть сложное меню на `PyQt`, форма для приложения лежит [**layout.py**](https://gitlab.com/adtsvetkov/lab2/-/blob/develop/src/layout.py), сам код  - [**goui.py**](https://gitlab.com/adtsvetkov/lab2/-/blob/develop/src/goui.py).

1. Главные составляющие моего `layout` - `MplCanvas`, обернутый в `VerticalLayout` и `QGroupBox`. Мне удалось настроить окно так, чтобы при изменении его размера изменялись и размеры элементов, однако при открытии окна на весь экран получается, что объекты слишком непропорциональны:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос в том, как правильно настроить пропорции при масштабировании? Например, хотелось бы получить **`3:1`** или **`4:1`** `MplCanvas`:`QGroupBox`, чтобы картинка не была слишком маленькая.

Также не очень понятно, как программно в коде настроить размер окна `MplCanvas`: при изменении размера окна окошко картинки хорошо уменьшает свой размер, но увеличивает только до определенного (видимо, константно заданного внутри `Qt Designer`, когда это меню рисовалось).

2. Немного непонятно, как сделать так, чтобы по нажатию кнопки приложение не вылетало (есть ли какой-то хороший способ кроме вечного цикла?): если все поля заполнены верно, программа отрабатывает до конца и можно вводить новые данные, но если, например, какое-то из полей не заполнено и вылетает `QMessageBox`, дальше уже ничего заполнять не получается, кнопки `OK` и `Reset` становятся неактивными и через какое-то время окошко закрывается с ошибкой. Такого же рода проблемы наблюдаются при нажатии кнопки `Reset` для очищения всех полей.

Вопрос в том, как правильно обработать нажатия на кнопку, чтобы меню закрылось только в случае его принудительного закрытия как диалогового окна (через крестик).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Ваши объекты `graphicsView` и `groupBox` управляются менеджером геометрии `grid`.

Вам следует обратить внимание на следующее:

> void QGridLayout::setRowStretch(int row, int stretch)
> Устанавливает коэффициент растяжения строки строки для растяжения. Первая строка - это номер `0`.
> Коэффициент растяжения относится к другим строкам в этой сетке.
> Ряды с более высоким коэффициентом растяжения занимают больше доступного места.
> Коэффициент растяжения по умолчанию равен `0`. 
> Если коэффициент растяжения равен `0` и никакая другая строка в этой таблице не может расти вообще, строка все равно может расти.

я также сделал некоторые изменения  пометки в тексте кода.

2. если некоторые поля не заполнены, вам надо выйти из метода `ok_button`.
   Например добавив некий флажок `flagError` ...

---

```
import sympy  
import numpy  
from PyQt5.QtCore import QEventLoop  
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialogButtonBox, QMessageBox  

from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr 
from matplotlib.colors import to_rgb      

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets 

#from MplCanvas import MplCanvas                    # <<<--- установите свой виджет MplCanvas
from pyqtgraph import PlotWidget                    # <<<--- это уберите

# import layout
class Ui_Newton(object):
    def setupUi(self, Newton):
        Newton.setObjectName("Newton")
        Newton.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.WindowModal)
        Newton.resize(850, 750)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Newton)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 20, 650, 500))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        

#        self.graphicsView = MplCanvas()           # <<<--- установите свой виджет MplCanvas
        self.graphicsView = PlotWidget()           # <<<--- это уберите        
        
        self.graphicsView.setObjectName("graphicsView")
        
#        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.graphicsView)
        
        self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.groupBox.setEnabled(True)
        self.groupBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 610, 930, 200))
        self.groupBox.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeading |
                                   QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft |
                                   QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.groupBox.setObjectName("groupBox")
        self.a = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.a.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(490, 60, 180, 30))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.a.setFont(font)
        self.a.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.a.setText("")
        self.a.setObjectName("a")
        self.b = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.b.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(720, 60, 180, 30))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.b.setFont(font)
        self.b.setText("")
        self.b.setObjectName("b")
        self.funcColor = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.groupBox)
        self.funcColor.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 140, 160, 30))
        self.funcColor.setObjectName("funcColor")
        self.funcColor.addItem("")
        self.funcColor.addItem("")
        self.funcColor.addItem("")
        self.funcColor.addItem("")
        self.tangentColor = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.groupBox)
        self.tangentColor.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 140, 160, 30))
        self.tangentColor.setObjectName("tangentColor")
        self.tangentColor.addItem("")
        self.tangentColor.addItem("")
        self.tangentColor.addItem("")
        self.tangentColor.addItem("")
        self.function = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.function.setEnabled(True)
        self.function.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 60, 190, 30))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.function.setFont(font)
        self.function.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.IBeamCursor))
        self.function.setWhatsThis("")
        self.function.setAccessibleName("")
        self.function.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.function.setInputMask("")
        self.function.setText("")
        self.function.setClearButtonEnabled(False)
        self.function.setObjectName("function")
        self.OK_NOK = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox(self.groupBox)
        self.OK_NOK.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(720, 120, 180, 60))
        self.OK_NOK.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        self.OK_NOK.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok |
                                       QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Reset)
        self.OK_NOK.setObjectName("OK_NOK")
        self.Inserta = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.Inserta.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(490, 30, 130, 20))
        self.Inserta.setObjectName("Inserta")
        self.Inserfunc = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.Inserfunc.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 30, 250, 20))
        self.Inserfunc.setObjectName("Inserfunc")
        self.Insertb = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.Insertb.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(720, 30, 130, 20))

# Текстовая строка интерпретируется как текст в формате Markdown. 
# Это значение перечисления было добавлено в Qt 5.14.
# Раскомментируйте строку ниже, если у вас версия Qt 5.14 + .               !!!          
#        self.Insertb.setTextFormat(QtCore.Qt.MarkdownText)
        
        self.Insertb.setWordWrap(True)
        self.Insertb.setObjectName("Insertb")
        self.TangColor = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.TangColor.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 110, 250, 20))
        self.TangColor.setObjectName("TangColor")
        self.FuncColor = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.FuncColor.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 110, 250, 20))
        self.FuncColor.setObjectName("FuncColor")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 30, 190, 20))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.variable = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.variable.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 60, 200, 30))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.variable.setFont(font)
        self.variable.setText("")
        self.variable.setObjectName("variable")
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.groupBox)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(490, 140, 150, 30))
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(490, 110, 160, 20))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        Newton.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(Newton)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 910, 25))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        Newton.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(Newton)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        Newton.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(Newton)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Newton)

    def retranslateUi(self, Newton):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Newton.setWindowTitle(_translate("Newton", "Newton functions"))
        self.groupBox.setTitle(_translate("Newton",
                                          "Put data about your function here"))
        self.a.setPlaceholderText(_translate("Newton",
                                             "Put a value of [a, b] here"))
        self.b.setPlaceholderText(_translate("Newton",
                                             "Put b value of [a, b] here"))
        self.funcColor.setItemText(0, _translate("Newton", "blue"))
        self.funcColor.setItemText(1, _translate("Newton", "red"))
        self.funcColor.setItemText(2, _translate("Newton", "green"))
        self.funcColor.setItemText(3, _translate("Newton", "yellow"))
        self.tangentColor.setItemText(0, _translate("Newton", "red"))
        self.tangentColor.setItemText(1, _translate("Newton", "blue"))
        self.tangentColor.setItemText(2, _translate("Newton", "green"))
        self.tangentColor.setItemText(3, _translate("Newton", "yellow"))
        self.function.setPlaceholderText(_translate("Newton",
                                                    "Put your function here"))
        self.Inserta.setText(_translate("Newton",
                                        "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\""
                                        " font-size:10pt; font-weight:600;\">"
                                        "Insert </span><span style=\" "
                                        "font-size:10pt; font-weight:600; "
                                        "font-style:italic; text-decoration: "
                                        "underline;\">a</span></p>"
                                        "</body></html>"))
        self.Inserfunc.setText(_translate("Newton",
                                          "<html><head/><body>"
                                          "<p><span style=\" "
                                          "font-size:10pt; font-weight:600;\">"
                                          "Insert function</span>"
                                          "</p></body></html>"))
        self.Insertb.setText(_translate("Newton",
                                        "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" "
                                        "font-size:10pt; "
                                        "font-weight:600;\">Insert "
                                        "</span>"
                                        "<span style=\" font-size:10pt; "
                                        "font-weight:600; font-style:italic; "
                                        "text-decoration: underline;\">b"
                                        "</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.TangColor.setText(_translate("Newton",
                                          "<html><head/>"
                                          "<body><p><span style=\" "
                                          "font-size:10pt; font-weight:600;\">"
                                          "Choose tangent color</span></p>"
                                          "</body></html>"))
        self.FuncColor.setText(_translate("Newton",
                                          "<html><head/><body><p>"
                                          "<span style=\" "
                                          "font-size:10pt; font-weight:600;"
                                          "\">Choose function color</span>"
                                          "</p></body></html>"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Newton",
                                      "<html><head/><body><p>"
                                      "<span style=\" font-size:10pt;"
                                      " font-weight:600;\">"
                                      "Insert variable name</span>"
                                      "</p></body></html>"))
        self.variable.setPlaceholderText(_translate("Newton",
                                                    "Put your variable"
                                                    " name here"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("Newton", "0.001"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("Newton", "0.0001"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(2, _translate("Newton", "0.00001"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(3, _translate("Newton", "0.000001"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Newton", "<html><head/><body><p>"
                                                  "<span style=\" "
                                                  "font-size:10pt; "
                                                  "font-weight:600;\">"
                                                  "Choose accuracy</span>"
                                                  "</p></body></html>"))
#         self.graphicsView.axes.set_title("Newton method visualization")


class NewtonApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Newton):
    def __init__(self):
        super(NewtonApp, self).__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        
        grid_GroupBox = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.groupBox)
        grid_GroupBox.addWidget(self.Inserfunc, 0, 0)
        grid_GroupBox.addWidget(self.label, 0, 1)
        grid_GroupBox.addWidget(self.Inserta, 0, 2)
        grid_GroupBox.addWidget(self.Insertb, 0, 3)

        grid_GroupBox.addWidget(self.function, 1, 0)
        grid_GroupBox.addWidget(self.variable, 1, 1)
        grid_GroupBox.addWidget(self.a, 1, 2)
        grid_GroupBox.addWidget(self.b, 1, 3)

        grid_GroupBox.addWidget(self.FuncColor, 2, 0)
        grid_GroupBox.addWidget(self.TangColor, 2, 1)
        grid_GroupBox.addWidget(self.label_2, 2, 2, 1, 1)

        grid_GroupBox.addWidget(self.funcColor, 3, 0)
        grid_GroupBox.addWidget(self.tangentColor, 3, 1)
        grid_GroupBox.addWidget(self.comboBox, 3, 2)
        grid_GroupBox.addWidget(self.OK_NOK, 3, 3,
                                alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        # Класс QGridLayout размещает виджеты в сетке.                   # !!!
        # Больше читаем https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgridlayout.html#details  # !!!
        self.grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.graphicsView, 0, 1, 1, 3)        
        self.grid.addWidget(self.groupBox, 1, 0, 1, 5)                   # +
        self.grid.setRowStretch(0, 1)                                    # +++
        self.grid.setRowStretch(1, 0)                                    # +++

        self.setTabOrder(self.function, self.variable)
        self.setTabOrder(self.variable, self.a)
        self.setTabOrder(self.a, self.b)
        self.setTabOrder(self.b, self.funcColor)
        self.setTabOrder(self.funcColor, self.tangentColor)
        self.setTabOrder(self.tangentColor, self.comboBox)
        self.setTabOrder(self.comboBox, self.OK_NOK)

        self.function.setFocus()

        self.OK_NOK.button(QDialogButtonBox.Ok).clicked.connect(self.ok_button)
        self.OK_NOK.button(QDialogButtonBox.Reset).clicked.connect(self.reset)

    def newton_method(self, a: float, b: float, function: str, x: str,
                      eps: float, func_col: str, tan_col: str, display=True) \
            -> float:

        # parsing function
        f = parse_expr(function)
        variable = sympy.Symbol(x)
        derivative = sympy.diff(f)
        x_start = (b - a) / 2

        # drawing function
        h = (b - a) / 1000
        X = numpy.arange(a, b, h)
        Y = [f.subs(variable, x) for x in X]
        if display:
            self.graphicsView.axes.cla()
            self.graphicsView.axes.set_title("Newton method for function "
                                             + function + " on [" + str(a)
                                             + ", " + str(b) + "]")
            self.graphicsView.axes.plot(X, Y, color=to_rgb(func_col))
            self.graphicsView.draw()
            self.show()

        while not (f.subs(variable, x_start) < eps):
            if display:
                loop = QEventLoop()
                QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(1000, loop.quit)  # 2000 = 2 seconds
                loop.exec()
                self.graphicsView.axes.cla()
                self.graphicsView.axes.plot(X, Y, color=to_rgb(func_col))
                self.graphicsView.axes.plot(x_start,
                                            f.subs(variable, x_start), 'ko')
                # drawing tangent
                Y_tangent = [
                    derivative.subs(variable, x_start) * x -
                    derivative.subs(variable, x_start) * x_start
                    + f.subs(variable, x_start) for x in X]
                self.graphicsView.axes.plot(X, Y_tangent,
                                            color=to_rgb(tan_col))
                self.graphicsView.axes.set_title("Newton method for function "
                                                 + function + " on [" + str(a)
                                                 + ", " + str(b) + "]")
                self.graphicsView.draw()
                self.show()

            # new point
            x_start = x_start - f.subs(variable,
                                       x_start) / derivative.subs(variable,
                                                                  x_start)
        return f.subs(variable, x_start)

    def ok_button(self) -> None:
       
        flagError = False                                                      # +++
        
        user_function = self.function.text()
        if not user_function:
            QMessageBox.about(self.centralWidget(),
                              "Message", "Enter your function, please")
            flagError = True                                                    # +++
        variable = self.variable.text()
        if not variable:
            QMessageBox.about(self.centralWidget(),
                              "Message", "Enter your variable, please")
            flagError = True                                                    # +++
        left = self.a.text()
        if not left:
            QMessageBox.about(self.centralWidget(),
                              "Message", "Enter your left border, please")
            flagError = True                                                    # +++
        right = self.b.text()
        if not right:
            QMessageBox.about(self.centralWidget(),
                              "Message", "Enter your right border, please")
            flagError = True                                                     # +++
        
        if flagError:                                                            # +++
            QMessageBox.about(self.centralWidget(),                              # +++
                     "Error", "Исправьте пожалуйста ошибки указанные вам!")      # +++
            return                                                               # +++  !!!
                              
        functionColor = self.funcColor.currentText()
        tangentColor = self.tangentColor.currentText()
        accuracy = self.comboBox.currentText()
        self.newton_method(float(left), float(right),
                           user_function, variable,
                           float(accuracy), functionColor,
                           tangentColor)

    def reset(self) -> None:
        self.function.clear()
        self.variable.clear()
        self.a.clear()
        self.b.clear()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle("Fusion")
    form = NewtonApp()
    form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое за Ваш ответ и подробное объяснение!

Comment: @Angelika пожалуйста